# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type '[.DataRow]', pero se requiere un tipo '.IEnumerable[Entities.Requerimiento]'

Tags: c#

El error que se encontró al tratar de realizar una vista.

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataRow]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Entities.Requerimiento]'.

el método desde donde se llama en el Backend y realiza la Consulta

```
    public static List<DataRow> ConsultarRequerimiento()
    {

        DataTable dtRequerimientos;
        dtRequerimientos = RequerimientoPersistence.GetAllRequerimientos();

        List<DataRow> lstRequerimientos = dtRequerimientos.AsEnumerable().ToList();

        return lstRequerimientos;
    }
```

La pregunta es como convertir ese dataRow en entidades de tipo Requerimiento se tiene de esta forma

```
    public class Requerimiento
{

        public int RequerimientoID { get; set; }

        public string NombreRequerimiento { get; set; }

        public string AlcanceRequerimiento { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaSolicitud { get; set;}

        public int AplicativoID { get; set; }

}
```

Hace algún tiempo no trabajo con ADO net, y no se esta utilizando EF.

Comment: Y qué has intentado? Imagino que el DataRow es una representación de una fila del dataset devuelto por la base de datos. Ya intentaste consultar los datos del DataRow? Puedes consultar valores por nombre: `string valorCelda= row["NombreColumnaBD"].ToString();`

Comment: @Arriel si estas en lo correcto, lo que deseo es convertir cada columna/fila en atributo de la clase requerimiento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues, si no estás utilizando EF, entonces tendrás que hacerlo *a mano*.

Una solución sencilla, es pasar el objeto DataRow al constructor de Requerimiento, y asignar las propiedades una a una. Veo que el error menciona el ViewData así que voy a asumir que estás utilizando AspNet MVC. Corrígeme si me equivoco, por favor.

Por ejemplo:

```
public Requerimiento(DataRow dr) 
{
     RequerimientoID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RequerimientoID"].ToString());
     NombreRequerimiento =  dr["NombreRequerimiento "].ToString();
     AlcanceRequerimiento =  dr["AlcanceRequerimiento "].ToString();
     FechaSolicitud = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FechaSolicitud "].ToString());
     AplicativoID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AplicativoID "].ToString());     

}
```

Luego, en tu controlador (o tu clase de lógica de negocios):

```
public List<Requerimiento> GetListaRequerimientoFromDataRow(List<DataRow> listaDataRow)
{
   var listaRequerimiento = new List<Requerimiento>();
   listaDataRow.ForEach(dr => {
       listaRequerimiento.Add(new Requerimiento(dr));

   });
   return listaRequerimiento;
}
```

Y en el retorno de la vista

```
// ... codigo de lo que sea que hagas.
List<DataRow> lstRequerimientos = dtRequerimientos.AsEnumerable().ToList();
var modelListaRequerimientos = GetListaRequerimientoFromDataRow(lstRequerimientos);
return View(modelListaRequerimientos);
```

Y listo.